# Replicate nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, nested

I am trying to replicate nested attributes in my model. The params that are passed when I create a new object through the GUI are:

tenant_script_call"=>{"name"=>"TEST_01", "script_id"=>"12", "script_call_arguments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"script_argument_id"=>"16", "argumentable_id"=>"43", "argumentable_type"=>"AstQueue"}, "1"=>{"script_argument_id"=>"17", "value"=>""}, "2"=>{"script_argument_id"=>"18", "value"=>""}, "3"=>{"script_argument_id"=>"19", "argumentable_id"=>"250", "argumentable_type"=>"Playlist"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

I am trying to automate this in my controller. I have tried:

```
TenantScriptCall.new(:name => "TEST_01", :location_id => location.id, :script_id => 12, :script_call_arguments_attributes [:script_argument_id => 16, :argumentable_id => self.id, :argumentable_type => "AstQueue", [:script_argument_id => 17, :value => "", [:script_argument_id => 18, :value => "", [:script_argument_id => 19, :argumentable_id => Playlist.last.id, :argumentable_type => "Playlist"]]]])
```

and

```
TenantScriptCall.new(:name => "TEST_01", :location_id => location.id, :script_id => 12, :script_call_arguments_attributes [:script_argument_id => 16, :argumentable_id => self.id, :argumentable_type => "AstQueue"] [:script_argument_id => 17, :value => ""] [:script_argument_id => 18, :value => ""] [:script_argument_id => 19, :argumentable_id => Playlist.last.id, :argumentable_type => "Playlist"])
```

As well as a few different variations. Can someone point me in the right direction or share some knowledge/wisdom please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private method

```
def tenant_params
   params.require(:tenant).permit(:column_names)
end
```

And now whenever u want to create. You just do this.

```
ModelName.create(tenant_params)
```

Comment: Can I set the values to their respective key this way? That's what I am ultimately trying to do. Replicate the key "and" its value for the params passed. I need to set them myself.

Comment: If your params is tenant_params={:key=>value}. where in Key is a column in a database. The above way will work . it will set key as column attribute in model and value as its value that needs to be saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your calls are a bit flawed. What are `location` and `self` in this context?

Your model definition should be something like this:

```
class TenantScriptCall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :script_call_arguments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :script_call_arguments
end
```

And then, if you want to pass input from the UI:

```
TenantScriptCall.new(params[:tenant_script_call])
```

should work.

Ultimately you should filter the input with `permit`, like @hemali pointed out.

Comment: Location is passed as an argument to this method from the controller I am calling it from. I didn't feel it was relevant since all I was asking was how do I replicate the params that I provided. All I want to do is recreate them on my own in my model. Both key and value through a create method. I am taking the params the UI is passing from my development log and trying to recreate them in my model. I cannot seem to get my question answered. Probably due to the way I am asking. Ill have to mess with it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you want to perform a nested model creation without actually receiving any input from UI, but to do it manually with a single method call? I guess a lot easier it would be to create all the nested instances, then pass them to parent model association and save. Would that do the trick for you? If so, if you'd have some trouble accomplishing it, I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: Krzysztof, yes. Exactly. What I want to accomplish will work. I have done this in another model. Just not as heavily nested. I have to do this with 4 separate models. Once something in the GUI is created, I have to automate another creation process. For example: If I create a huntlist, then after save it will automatically create a destination. That is why I grabbed the params and am trying to make a new/create method in my model to automate this. To replicate the creation of the params. Like I said, I have done this with the first one. It just wasn't as heavily nested.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
  def auto_create_destination_for_ast_queue(location)
    auto_destination_name_queue = AstQueue.last.name.split(/-/)[0]
    TenantScriptCall.new(:name => auto_destination_name_queue,
      :location_id => location.id, 
      :script_id => 12,
      :script_call_arguments_attributes => [{:script_argument_id => 16,
      :argumentable_id => AstQueue.last.id, 
      :argumentable_type => "AstQueue"}, 
        {:script_argument_id => 19, 
        :argumentable_id => 3, 
        :argumentable_type => "Playlist"}]).save
  end
```